# What is the difference between for(auto& x:A) and for(auto &x:A) in C++

Tags: c++, foreach, reference

I have an int type array, and I want to reference its values using a range based for loop, but I can't find the difference between using for(auto& x:A) and for(auto &x:A). Both are valid in my compiler and give the same output. Is there any diference?

Here is the code i'm using and the output:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    //Using any of the two following lines, there seems to be no diference in the output.
    //for (auto& x : A) x=1;
    //for (auto &x : A) x=1;

    for (auto x : A) cout << x << " ";
}
```

And the output is:
`1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`

Comment: Check [http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

> but I can't find the difference between using for(auto& x:A) and for(auto &x:A)

No differences.

Same as pointer type: `int* p` or `int *p` are the same thing.

Both styles are correct. However, see this which indicates it may be better for `&` and `*` to be closer to the variable name (ie prefer the later style):

https://www.quora.com/Where-should-I-put-the-asterisk-for-pointers-in-C++-Is-it-int*-ptr-int-*-ptr-or-int-*ptr

> In my experience with many clients, large and small, and several
>   different coding standards, the overwhelming majority attach the
>   asterisk to the variable name (i.e., int *ptr)